# Converting compoenentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps and my conversion isn't working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, components

Converting a react app to no longer use componentWillReceiveProps to getDerivedStateFromProps and my conversion isn't working for some reason.  The original shows errors if there are any and if both sets of errors are not there, it changes the state to as to close the dialog, make the body and empty string and clear any errors if perhaps initially loaded.

Any help would be appreciated.

Old functioning code:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.UI.errors) {
    this.setState({
      errors: nextProps.UI.errors,
    });
  }
  if (!nextProps.UI.errors && !nextProps.UI.loading) {
    this.setState({ body: '', open: false, errors: {} });
  }
}
```

New non-functioning code:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
  if (props.UI.errors) {
    return {
      errors: props.UI.errors,
    };
  }
  if (!props.UI.errors && !props.UI.loading) {
    return {
      body: '',
      open: false,
      errors: {},
    };
  }
  return null;
}
```

Sorry. The issue is that the button will not pop up with the new code.  When I comment out the second if statement I get the modal and the errors when nothing is submitted.  But then the state isn't returned to its original state.

I am looking at that documentation and already have a handlesubmit function.  I put the second if statement in my handle submit function but get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property "errors" of undefined"

Here is my new submit with that if statment.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.UI.errors && !this.state.UI.loading) {
      this.setState({
        body: "",
        open: false,
        errors: {},
      });
    }
    this.props.postBroadcast({ body: this.state.body });
  };
```

Comment: Are you sure `getDerivedStateFromProps` is what you actually want here? see: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#when-to-use-derived-state

Comment: `my conversion isn't working` You forgot to specify what `not working` means. Are errors not going away, do you get an error in the console, is the dialog not closing ...... I also agree with the other comment, why not use the props directly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up running getDerivedStateFromProps and componentDidUpdate and it is functional now with now depreciated components

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
if (props.UI.errors) {
  return {
    errors: props.UI.errors,
  };
}
return null;
```

}

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.UI.errors !== this.props.UI.errors && !this.props.UI.errors) {
      this.setState({
        errors: {},
        open: false,
        body: "",
      });
    }
  }
```